# Is it possible to change where echo outputs?

Tags: php, echo

I want to know if i can output echoes into a variable. What i mean is that echo takes multiple arguments, so i can use echo to output something like:

```
echo 'Welcome ', $name, ', we are here to help!';
```

I find that it is cleaner and easier to maintain than concatenating strings and i cant stand complex syntax.
Is it possible to make echo to just return a value? So i could do something like

```
$string_not_meant_for_being_displayed = echo('Lorem', $ipsum);
```

Alternatively, is it possible to create a function that takes infinitely number of arguments?

Performance is not actually an issue.

Comment: I suppose you could do this through Class objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem creating another function, as below:

```
function ee(){
     foreach(func_get_args() as $arg) {
        $v .= $arg;
     }
     return $v;
}

$name = "John";
echo ee("Welcome ", $name, ", we are here to help");
$string_not_meant_to_be_displayed = ee("His name is ", $name);
```

This way i can use multiple arguments just like echo but output it somewhere else if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible to create a function that takes infinitely number of arguments. You just have to use `func_num_args()` to get the number of arguments supplied.

```
function abcd(){
     $numargs = func_num_args();
     echo "Number of arguments: $numargs\n";
}

abcd(1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, i was able to create the function with it.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to store echo into a variable?

To use multiple arguments, use double quote syntax:

> echo "Welcome $firstname, $lastname. We are here to help! ";

Comment: It's because echo takes multiple arguments, as i said, i feel concatenating string and using double quotes syntax is not so clear.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confuse of your question but on how I understand it,

inside your function, instead of using echo, use return.

example you have a function,

```
function myFunction()
{
     $name = "Leonardo";

     return $name;
}
```

in that case you can use the returned value as variable. so the $name variable has now a value of "Leonardo";

Answer (score 1):

User `sprintf`, `vsprintf`, `printf` instead

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php

Answer (score 1):

If you *must* use echo, I believe you want to look into using output buffering: [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_get_flush](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-flush.php).

**Example:**

```
ob_start();
echo "This is a test";
$string_not_meant_to_be_displayed = ob_get_flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with something like this ...

```
$name='Goober';
$thing="Welcome $name, we are here to help!";
echo $thing;
echo "\n";
```

Comment: I feel double quotes syntax is just not clean(it can be clean working with a few variables, but it becomes a mess when working with arrays, also i can not put a value returned by a function without concatenating.

Answer (score 1):

what about this ??

```
<?php

function extended_echo($text, $values) {
  $count = 1;
  foreach ($values as $values) {
    $text = preg_replace("#@" . $count . "@#", $values, $text);
    $count++;
  }
  return $text;
}

$myValues = array();
$myValues[0] = 'TechNew.In';
$myValues[2] = 'tech';
$myValues[3] = 'dino babu';

$myText = "Hello, @1@ is an awesome @2@ website by @3@.";

echo extended_echo($myText, $myValues);
?>
```

Output

```
Hello, TechNew.In is an awesome tech website by dino babu.
```

Comment: Nice solution. Tough i've modified it so i can use it like my example.